# How do I stream from a second, dedicated computer?

Tags: streaming

I play games on my laptop, and they run at about 30-45 FPS, which is bearable for me. But when I try to stream, the frame rate drops to 20 or lower, which is unplayable for me.

I have a second computer, though (a Mac; the laptop is Windows 7), and I'm wondering if there is any way to stream the game content from my laptop using my Mac. To clarify, I would still have the game running on the laptop. I just want the Mac to deal with the streaming part to improve performance on the gaming computer.

Is this possible, and how would I go about doing it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about generic streaming.  While streaming is something that gamers do, it itself is not a gaming-specific activity, therefore does not belong here.

Comment: Any recommendation of where to ask this?

Comment: @Frank Meta disagrees with you: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/am-i-allowed-to-ask-questions-about-streaming

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness "As a rule of thumb, if you can remove every mention of games or gaming from the question and have it still fully describe your problem, then it's probably off-topic".  No game mentioned.  Problem still exists.  Off-topic.

Comment: @Frank The meta discussion has established that streaming is on topic, therefore your personal opinion does not matter.

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness That quote is from the highest upvoted answer on meta.  Streaming, while something that gamers do, is, by itself, not a gaming-specific activity, as I said.  If there's a problem with a *specific* game, that's hindering the streaming, there's no issue of whether it's on-topic or not.  This, though, isn't.  Generic streaming isn't on-topic here.  No game problem = off-topic.

Comment: @Frank ...Seriously, stop being so tight about what is off topic or not. Streaming games is a particular gaming problem. you don't just want to stream, you want to play remotely. It involves lag issues which are higher than for a regular problem. It involves porting gamepad input from one computer to the other, this kind of things. How is that not a gaming question? There is no need to be so tight about "it's too generic, not a gaming question". The only thing you achieve is scaring off a newcomer.

Comment: @techgod52 - when you talk about "streaming", do you mean playing on the other computer, or playing from the mac, while the game is being run by the other computer? Because it's not fully clear. (Or I understand badly)

Comment: @Gnoupi Any question that involves technical expertise (which this does) has to pass the acid test.  If you remove games from the question, and the problem still remains, it isn't on-topic here.  That's the way it works.  This question doesn't even *mention* games, other than the framerate drops when running them.  This problem still exists, even without games, therefore doesn't belong here.  And according to Meta, no, it's not on-topic.

Comment: @Frank - my issue is still the same old one, like on SU in the early days. At some point, by strongly policing what is or isn't off-topic, no one even asked the poor guy for details on his exact problem. It looks like your thought process was "streaming, meta declared it off-topic, voting to close, get out of my lawn". Not the most welcoming attitude, that's all.

Comment: @Gnoupi I mean stream the game from my laptop to Twitch using my Mac

Comment: @techgod52 - Ok, I think I see what you want to do. Tell me if I'm wrong. You want to stream the picture from your gaming computer (the laptop, win7), but without the calculation cost of it. As such, you would want to use the second computer to "do the streaming", so that the first one doesn't suffer from the processing cost?

Comment: @Gnoupi Exactly.

Comment: Hi I am the toxic part of this website. It is me.

Comment: FYI: Gnoupi is right about this being game-specific enough.

Comment: @badp - a bit less about my first interpretation of the need, though. I thought it was about streaming from the strong computer to the other, while playing from a different location, a bit like what Steam proposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Broadcasting gameplay from one computer to another?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14608/broadcasting-gameplay-from-one-computer-to-another)

Comment: For the record, I agree with Frank above that this is off-topic, but also accept that consensus is against me. Doesn't change the apparent duplication, though.

Comment: @pppery As far as I can tell, the two questions are not duplicates. The other one is about how to stream your gameplay, while this one is about how to use a different computer for streaming than the one you play on.

Comment: @pppery as quoted by Frank, I still think this question is off-topic

Comment: @pinckerman As replied to Frank by user28015 and other users, the community consensus is that these types of questions are on-topic: [Am I allowed to ask questions about streaming?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7958/4797)

Comment: @galacticninja "..on-topic so long as ...", as also mentioned before by Frank. Replace gaming with, say, 3D modelling, and the problem still stands. Close vote from me as well.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about streaming and not tied exclusively to gaming (see comments).

Comment: @Joachim Personally, I find it hard to separate "streaming" from "gaming", especially in this context. I think the OP asked this question as a gamer and wanted an answer from a gamer’s POV rather than a general computer user's POV. If I were in the OP’s situation and had to ask the question, I would choose Arqade over Super User to ask this question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need for that is a Video Splitter Cable along with a Video Capture card to capture the video after it has "left" your gpu. You would attach it over the output of your video card. Then you could feed this image to a capture card in your Mac.

While this works, it is a pricey solution. I would rather recommend getting a real computer or to try to play those games on your Mac. If you own your games on Steam, chances are high that the games in Question have Steam Play, which makes you own them on Mac, Linux and PC at the same time.

For streaming or recording games I recommend an i5 at minimum or even an i7 along with 16GB of RAM and a fast Hard Disk with 7200 RPM in case of recording or even a SSD.

Using Tools like NVIDIA Shadowplay or AMD Gaming Evolved can significantly cut down on your frame loss while streaming/recording, so I recommend trying those too.

Comment: Oh, nice, I haven't thought about those options. I was going to answer that this is not possible, since the work would have to be done anyway, but indeed, such device can capture the image without the processing cost.

Comment: I have 16gb of RAM, an 3rd gen i5, but an integrated Intel HD Mobile 4000 graphics card/chip/whatever, so that hinders performance a lot.

Comment: Can I use Shadowplay w/o an NVIDIA card?

Comment: @techgod No I don't think so. Use raptr for that, aka AMD Gaming Evolved. It comes with integrated Twitch Streaming Support.. Reason is, that AMD and NVIDIA have both different optimized frame grabbing techniques. OBS also has a AMD Version of their streaming tool:  https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/obs-fork-branch-with-amd-vce-support.13996/

Comment: @techgod52 Oh, you have actually no mobile dedicated GPU in there? Welp, that is an issue :D. How good is your Mac? Can you try to play on that one?

Comment: @NoneOfYourBusiness It's a Mac mini 4gb ram, 3rd gen i5, and same (but non-mobile) graphics. So, no XD

Comment: I'm installing raptr right now, looks pretty great.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to stream is to have a two PC-setup. Streaming eats a lot of CPU power and there is no way you will have better stream quality with one PC than with a two PC setup. Unless you don't have a PC with two CPUs inside it, which is quite exotic and expensive as hell I guess. And it's not for gaming.

So you can buy an avermedia live gamer portable lite (around 150$) to save some bucks and you don't need any video splitter. Just make sure that you can use avermedia's HDMI input (check your laptop video output). And you will probably need an HDMI cable, if it doesn't come with the capture card.

The question is -  is your laptop capable of sending picture simultaneously to the laptop screen and through the laptop's video output.

The difficulty about a two PC setup is sending audio to the second PC. You can resolve that with a 3.5 mm audio-cable splitters.

With the capture card, you will fit in 200$ I think, if you don't have a professional MIC with XLR or USB output. Also there are some ways to send audio through the lan.

Comment: The suggested streaming device shouldn't have any issue with audio over HDMI from a laptop. The HDMI standard carries both audio and video, and the device's specs explicitly call out that it handles the audio signal.